# Prove that $||v||^2 ≥ \dfrac{1}{n}$ - alternative way

Tags: linear-algebra, inner-products, cauchy-schwarz-inequality

Let $v$ = $
  \begin{align}
     & \begin{bmatrix}
           x_{1} \\
           x_{2} \\
           \vdots \\
           x_{n}
         \end{bmatrix}
  \end{align}
 ∈ \Bbb R^n$   s.t $x_1, ...,x_n ≥ 0$ and  $\sum_{i=1}^{n}x_i =1$. Prove that $||v||^2 ≥ \dfrac{1}{n}$. The official solution uses Cauchy-Schwartz inequality but I solved it in a much simpler way. By definition, The standard norm is $||v||^2$ = $(\sqrt{\langle v,v \rangle})^2= $$(\sqrt{(\sum_{i=1}^{n}(x_i)^2})^2$ =$\sum_{i=1}^{n}x_i$ $*$ $\sum_{i=1}^{n}x_i$ (finite sum) = $1$ ≥ $\dfrac{1}{n}$ for every $n≥1$. There is something wrong here? It looks too naive.

Comment: The equality $(\sqrt{(\sum_{i=1}^{n}(x_i)^2})^2 = \sum_{i=1}^{n}x_i * \sum_{i=1}^{n}x_i$ is incorrect.

Comment: In particular, if $x_i = 1/n$ then $\| v \|^2 = \sum_{i = 1}^n \tfrac{1}{n^2} = \tfrac 1n$

Comment: In particular,$\dfrac{1}{n}$ is the minimum value of $\sqrt{\sum_{i=1}^{n}x_i^2}$. You can use Lagrange multiplier method.

Answer (score -1):

-Take into account that I am just a student so I hope that my answer is correct.

-You have a more simple prove.

1- We [know that](https://he.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D7%90%D7%99-%D7%A9%D7%95%D7%95%D7%99%D7%95%D7%9F_%D7%94%D7%9E%D7%9E%D7%95%D7%A6%D7%A2%D7%99%D7%9D) $\sqrt{\frac{\sum_{i=1}^n x_i^2}{n}} \geq \frac{\sum_{i=1}^n x_i}{n} = \frac{1}{n}$ as it is given $\sum_{i=1}^n x_i = 1 $.
-This cause that $\sqrt{\frac{\sum_{i=1}^n x_i^2}{n}} \geq \frac{\sum_{i=1}^n x_i}{n} = \frac{1}{n} \Rightarrow \sqrt{\sum_{i=1}^n x_i^2} \geq \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}} $

2- Now as $x^2$ is an increasing function fofr $x \geq 0$ we have that $0 \leq x_1 \leq x_2 \Rightarrow x_1^2 \leq x_2^2$. Apply to here it gives us $\| v \|^2 = \sum_{i=1}^n x_i^2 =(\sqrt{\sum_{i=1}^n x_i^2})^2 \geq (\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}})^2= \frac{1}{n}$

Q.E.D.

Comment: This is not a proof. The statement " We know that $\sqrt{\frac{\sum_{i=1}^n x_i^2}{n}} \geq \frac{\sum_{i=1}^n x_i}{n} = \frac{1}{n}$ as it is given $\sum_{i=1}^n x_i = 1 $ " is just re-stating the problem.

Comment: ‏‏‏@K.defaoite I don't understand where is the problem in what I ve written. I just use the assumption and know inequalities.

Comment: If you replace $\sqrt{\sum_i {x_i}^2}$ with $\Vert v \Vert $ , you have **literally** restated the problem.

Comment: For answer to be useful at all, you need to explain the referenced inequality and why it applies here. Otherwise it would be just as useful to leave a link to the Wikipedia in the comments of the original post.

Comment: @K.defaoite sorry I did not pay attention to the power of $2$ any way it doe not change a lot the prove I am going to edit my answer to complete it thank you!

Comment: @K.defaoite Here I have edited my answer I think it is good now. Please don't down vote if it is correct  :-)

Comment: Your point #1 is just a re-stated version of the original problem. It renders point #2 unecessary (nevermind the fact that point #2 is a very obvious thing anyway).

Comment: @K.defaoite I do not understand your criticize it is asked to us to prove $ ||v||_2≥1/n$ and that what I did.